# Servlet code causing NumberFormatException

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

My servlet code, for an online form-based booking system using Java, JSP and MySQL, keeps throwing a NumberFormatException at the line beginning at 'int customer'. There is nothing else wrong with my code, apart from here.

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

If I check for null or empty strings all I get is errors.

```
if (submit.equals("add booking")) {        
                int customerID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("customerID").trim());
                int routeID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("routeID").trim());
                String sailing = request.getParameter("sailing").trim();
                int noAdults = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noAdults").trim());
                int noChildren = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("noChildren").trim());
                String otherinfo = request.getParameter("otherinfo").trim();
                if (sailing.equalsIgnoreCase("")) {
                    url = "/scotiavalidation.jsp";
                } else {
                    bookingManager.addBooking(customerID, routeID, sailing, noAdults, noChildren, otherinfo);
                    int bookingID = 0;
                    bookingID = bookingManager.getBookingIdByAdd(bookingID);
                    request.setAttribute("bookingID", bookingID);
                    url = "/bookingConfirmation.jsp";
                }
```

I know I need a try catch block somewhere, but I can't figure it out. Can anyone suggest a solution?
My Glassfish 4.1.1 output looks like this:

```
Warning:   StandardWrapperValve[BookingServlet]: Servlet.service() for servlet BookingServlet threw exceptionjava.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
at controller.BookingServlet.processRequest(BookingServlet.java:46)
at controller.BookingServlet.doGet(BookingServlet.java:161)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1682)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:318)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:734)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:673)
at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:174)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:416)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:283)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:459)
at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:167)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:235)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:283)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:200)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:132)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:111)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:536)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:591)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:571)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm using sessions in My JSP pages. Here is a fragment:

```
<form name="addBookingForm" action="BookingServlet">
                <table cellspacing="8" border="0">
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><p><label for="customerID">Customer No:</label></p></td>
                        <td><p><%= session.getAttribute("customerID")%></p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td align="left"><p><label for="routeID">Cruise No:</label></p></td>
                        <td><select name="routeID" id="routeID" value="">
                                <option selected></option>
                                <option>322</option>
                                <option>323</option>
                                <option>324</option>
                            </select></td>
                    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integer.parseInt(value) .in here value may be not parsable as int. it may have alphabetical or some other characters. It's better to validate the user input first to check if that is a numeric value before phasing to int.

You can use Apache Commons Lang 3.5 NumberUtils.isCreatable or StringUtils.isNumeric.

To do the validation

Answer (score 0):

It seems your value for customerID is returned as string "null". You need validate  before casting it.You should also check your JSP why customerID is set as "null". You also need to check in your servlet.Something like

```
if (submit.equals("add booking")&&request.getParameter("customerID")!=null)
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message is clear:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "null"

You are parsing a `null` value as number. Are you sure that integer parameters are filled?.

Check for `null` pointers before call `Integer.parse` or `trim` functions.